# SQL - Reduce data before count() - subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a table with multiple columns and one of them is named `SoftwareVersion`. This column can be empty and its default value is `NULL`.

My dataset is around 26.5 million rows so I would like to reduce it before counting.

So I `SELECT * FROM Database WHERE "SoftwareVersion" IS NOT NULL` which is working perfectly.

From the reduced set of rows I want to `COUNT(SoftwareVersion)`.

I was thinking of a subquery but can´t figure out how to do this properly for my scenario.

Comment: Use a CTE. `with cteDemo as (SELECT * FROM Database WHERE SoftwareVersion IS NOT NULL) select * from cte` for example

Comment: Why not just do `SELECT COUNT(SoftwareVersion) FROM dbo.Database`? `COUNT` already ignores `NULL` values. (Side note, a table called `database` is very confusing..)

Comment: @Larnu i thought by filtering the null Values my Dataset gets smaller and the Count(*) is performed faster. Its really slow to count the SoftwareVersions and while testing some querys, by every little change its performed again and im waiting :) (the table is actually called ".dbo.AnalyticalHeartbeat" :)

Comment: And how expensive do you think it'll be to filter all those rows? `SELECT COUNT(YourColumn ) FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL) DT` is likely going to generate a *very* similar query plan to `SELECT COUNT(YourColumn ) FROM dbo.YourTable`

Comment: I see, i thought itll reduce the time by a lot. Is there maybe a better/faster way to Count all of the SoftwareVersions? Thanks for the help

Comment: If the overall row count with NULL in `SoftwareVersion` column  is great, than filtering before counting can improve query performance. For example, in my PostgreSQL table with overall 2000 rows `COUNT` without `WHERE ... IS NOT NULL` clause is 4 times slower then with it.
Meanwhile you should not use a subquery to filter rows, your query would be just like this
`SELECT COUNT(SoftwareVersion) FROM Database WHERE "SoftwareVersion" IS NOT NULL`. Of course you should have an index on `SoftwareVersion` column

Comment: `COUNT(SoftwareVersion)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` are you sure you don't want `COUNT(DISTINCT SoftwareVersion)`

Comment: Unless SQL is slow, you should not play games like this - the optimizer handles most of this for you.  You can create a filtered index on the non-null values for a column if you believe it is a significant fraction of the rows, but otherwise you don't need to try to work around the optimizer in most cases on this product.